# How to click the segmentedControl object and use it to change view?

Tags: cocoa, segments, nsbrowser

I want to implement just like interface builder segmented control, and click it to change views , I don't know under the segment if a NSBrowser or not. and how to change the view , can you give me some sample codes or a demo? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSSegmentedControl` for the segmented control, and a tabless `NSTabView` to switch between views. If it makes sense in your app, you could even bind both to the same user default and implement this without writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

A segmented control is an NSSegmentedControl.